# Is there a value in outlier.shape, or another approach for geom_boxplot, that will result in ring circle outliers?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

I was wondering if it is possible to have outliers that appear in geom_boxplot as ring circles like those shown here:

[image]

I can change the shapes to triangles, squares, asterixs, etc. by changing the values in outlier.shape but all appear to be filled. Any ideas?

On a side note is there any documentation that informs you what each value equates to in outlier.shape instead of trial and error? I've had zero luck searching online for such a source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I normally [just do an image search for "R pch" every time](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+pch&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS508US508&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=LZmeVYraBtjloATN6LKgBg&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1920&bih=979), but it's also documented in `?points`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape codes in `ggplot` are the same as in base R. See for example [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/).

Number 1 is an empty ring.

For example:

```
qplot(y = c(1, 50:55), x = 1, geom = 'boxplot', outlier.shape = 1, outlier.size = 5)
```

[image]